# Layer Turned Off But Pop Up Showing

Tags: arcobjects, web-mapping, arcgis-online, popup

I'm having an issue with my popup in my map made using ArcGIS online.

One of my group layers contain 4 layers. When I turn all of the layers in this group layer off, the second layer's popup still displays when I click on the map. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Also, for some reason, when I have all the layers in this group layer turned on, the second layer's pop up (polygon feature) shows before the 1st layer's popup (a point layer). How do I get the first layer's pop-up to show up first before the second layers?

Comment: Is the first layer really the first layer? I always thought that had to do with the ordering of the layers. The top layer always seems to show up first in my maps.

Comment: @jbchurchill Yup, the first layer in the group layer is on top of the second layer. But the second layer's popup shows first. I don't understand.